# Is there a simple way to create an array based on a string containing URL get variables?

Tags: php, ajax, string, url

I'm passing through a string via ajax to be used with PHP.

Example

```
home?area=Ohio&country=United%20States
```

How can I end up with an array that looks like the following?

```
array('area' => 'ohio', 'country' => 'United States');
```

Comment: What is the difference between the wanted array and `$_GET`?

Comment: `parse_str`, possibly in tandem with `parse_url` if you have an entire url and you need to seperate the query string out of it.

Comment: There isn't, the data is being sent to a different file via POST, so the GET variables aren't accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the current request's query string, try:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $output);

echo $output['area']; // Ohio
```

Comment: oh wicked, knew there had to be some function for it! cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
parse_str("area=Ohio&country=United%20States");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php